# In a Chrome Extension, how can I accurately retrieve the user's region/locale/country from their Chrome browser?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

How does Google detect the user's country to set the user's search page accordingly? I have searched around and cannot find a simple way of doing it.

Comment: Pretty sure the search page just reverse geocodes the users IP address since it's a web page and not an extension. You can do that from an extension but it wouldn't be using a Chrome specific API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the languages, which the user has set in the Chrome settings, like this:

```
chrome.i18n.getAcceptLanguages(function (list) {
    console.log(list);
});
```

For location, there is the location API (HTML5) - but the user must agree to share the location for it to work: http://html5demos.com/geo

Or you could use a geo IP service (IP is known only server side): http://freegeoip.net/json/

Answer (score 2):

To get locale of the browser window and the language the UI showed in, you can use:

```
chrome.i18n.getUILanguage()
```

Comment: `chrome.i18n.getUILanguage().split('-')[1]` will give you the two-letter ISO country code (I think in all cases, but haven't tested it extensively)

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked in the google developers api:

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/api_index

I guess it uses geolocation :)

Comment: Thanks for that. I was thinking along the lines of... if Google already does it on the user's browser, maybe the variable is stored somewhere to be easily retrieved.

Comment: actually, you can find it in chrome developer API, under location: 
https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/api_index

Comment: It says its available only in the dev API. Is that the same as saying, if the user's browser is a stable version of Chrome, then the chrome.location won't work?